# Last clicked image in array

Tags: arrays, processing

I have an array of images, when i click on one of them, I want it to loop and create a pattern. (This part already works). When i want to get the last clicked image out of my array i get a 'NullPointerException'

```java
PImage[] patronen = new PImage[7];
int pLength = patronen.length;
PImage selectedPatroon = patronen[patronen.length-1];

void setup(){
size(1024, 768);
}

void draw(){
 createPGrid();

image(selectedPatroon, xPos, yPos);
}

void createPGrid(){

for(int j = 0; j < gpLength; j++){
// Grid maanmaken
xPos = xOffset + ((j % cols) * (size+padding));
yPos = yOffset + ((j / cols) * (size+padding));

// Thumbs
patronen[j] = loadImage( j + ".png");
image(patronen[j], xPos, yPos);



// Check if thumb is clicked  
 if((mouseX >= xPos && mouseX <= xPos+size) && 
   (mouseY >= yPos && mouseY <= yPos+size)){ 

  if (mousePressed){
    // grid patronen
    xPos = 0;
    yPos = 0;

    // Loop pattern
    while( yPos < height ){
      while( xPos < width ){
        patronen[j] = loadImage(j + "groot" + ".png");
        selectedPatroon = patronen[j] 

        xPos += 500;
  }
  yPos +=500;
  xPos = 0;     
 }
 rect(xPos, yPos, size, size);
}
}
}
}
```

EDIT: The thing is, it works perfectly without

```
PImage selectedPatroon = patronen[patronen.length-1];
```

but then the looped pattern comes above all my others functions. And i want it to be under that.

Comment: looks like loadImage might be returning the null pointer

Comment: I don't see where you're getting the last clicked image. Have you posted that part of your code?

Comment: Its this part. 
PImage selectedPatroon = patronen[patronen.length-1];

Answer (score 0):

You are creating an array at the top of your code then setting an image to the last element in the array, but you're not populating the array first.

```
PImage[] patronen = new PImage[7];  <<< Blank 7 element array.
int pLength = patronen.length;
PImage selectedPatroon = patronen[patronen.length-1];
```

Comment: Aaaah, I see! But when i try it like this -> PImage[] patronen = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6}; (The numbers are the name of my png's.) I get the error 'cannot convert from int to PImage'. How do I fix this?

Comment: You are trying use an integer (in the array) to set the value of an image.  You will need to use code to set the value of the image to the image file based on the value of the integer.

Try looking here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/stf701f5(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Well the method will need to be different, but you still won't be able to set the value of an image to a number.

Answer (score 0):

To answer the questions you've put in the comments, you cannot populate an array of `PImage`s with `int`s, those are different variable types. Try something like this in `setup()`:

```java
PImage patronen = new PImage[7];
for(int i = 0; i < patronen.length; i++){
  patronen[i] = loadImage("image" + i + ".png"); // or whatever format your filenames are
}
```

The `loadImage(String name)` function returns a PImage, so you can insert it directly into your array. Just trying to insert the numbers won't work because the computer doesn't know that the numbers represent the filename without you telling it with `loadImage()`.